# What's the smallest travel case for a full suspension 26er?

Tags: mountain-bike

I want to travel with my full suspension 26er MTB. It seems like I should be able to pack it pretty small since the largest part of a road bike is usually the frame itself.

If I can unbolt the frame into two pieces, I feel it would take up no more room than the wheels would (which are small, being a 26er).

What's the smallest bike box I can get for traveling with this bike?

Answer (score 2):

It's pretty hard to recommend a size without knowing the details about your frame, etc.

For ideas for shipping and sizes you might stop at your local bike shop and check out the boxes the manufacturer uses to ship the bikes.